# How to remove a mid-run outdoor outlet

Tags: gfci, removal

I had a fountain in the middle of my yard. The fountain is now gone but my GFCI Outdoor box is still there and is in a mid-run, as I have another outlet against my far fence. The electrical is buried from my house to the fountain where it pops up (with the outdoor GFCI) then buried again to the far fence with another GFCI. How can I remove the fountain (mid run GFCI outlet)? Can I splice it, do I need a box? Can it be buried? I'd like to put lawn back over the top.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair a damaged UF cable](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21935/how-can-i-repair-a-damaged-uf-cable)

Comment: What type of installation, conduit or UF-B cable?

Comment: Code varies by country and local government.   Personally I would  at  the very least put in a junction box where you splice,  **and** maintain some sort of access tube or marker so you can always get at it.   If the wiring is inside a conduit, it really is better to pull a fresh run end to end

Comment: The answer @isherwood would be the same for me if UF no box is needed with a underground splice kit. But you will have to dig down to burry the splice.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the outlet box please? Do you want the option of putting an outlet back in at that location in the future?

Comment: I believe its conduit. Thanks for all the suggestions/answers. Box makes sense with the pull of new wires to the end outlet. After removing the outlet I am going to bury it and plant lawn.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's feeding other receptacles the junction box cannot be buried. Meaning you can feed-through the circuit and put a blank cover over it but it must remain visible and accessible.